# How to force 'django.contrib.sites' to be migrated first?

Tags: python, django

When using `python manage.py makemigrations` on a project that uses functions from the `django.contrib.sites`, I always received the error:

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: django_site

If I comment out the parts of my code that use app, and run `makemigrations`, it works. Then I can uncomment and use normally.

Even tho this (bad) approach works, but I would like to make it work correctly. I already put this app in the top of `settings.INSTALLED_APPS`, but it does not solve it.

The file that uses the sites app is a helper file with some utility functions, in the same folder that `settings.py` is. I tried moving to some app, and tried deleting all the migrations made by the project apps, and it also didn't solved it.

Comment: Something is accessing the `django_site` table before _any_ app is migrated. You need to fix that. Can you show the full traceback?

Comment: @knbk That was it. Want to post this reply as a comment, so I can reply it with the details?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [knbk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2615075/knbk), i found the answer.

I was using the function `Site.objects.get_current().domain` in a global scope variable of a helper file, that was accessing `django_site` before the migrations were being made.

Making it a local scope inside a function made it run only after the migrations were completed.